# Can't get slds-truncate to function properly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, slds

I have an aura component that displays a list of articles and needs to be responsive. I have a pretty simple HTML setup to render the columns inside an slds-grid element:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.articles}" var="article">
       <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-large-size_1-of-2" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 4px;">
            <li class="slds-truncate">
                <a href="{!article.link}" class="topic-link" target="_blank">
                    {!article.label}
                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</div>
```

The issue is that when the component renders, the truncation *appears* to be fine:

[image]

However, as you can see, the blue box is the size of it's container, which flows into element next to it in the grid. I was expecting the container to be flexible and fit snugly with the truncated text, like in the documentation:

[image]

The problem is that when I resize the page, especially on mobile, the whole component will only size down to the size of the largest text, and so the box will break the bounds of the viewable area on mobile. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get it to behave this way.

Additionally, I have tried moving the `slds-truncate` attribute to within the `a` tag, but that didn't work. I also tried putting the `a` tag in a div, but that gave me really wonky results–it positioned the text underneath the `li` bullet. I appreciate any help anybody might have.

Comment: It is taking from `slds-size_1-of-1` class. You can try with `slds-size_1-of-2`